# Windows Azure Java SDK example?

Tags: java, windows, azure, sdk

Well, that's it. I don't know where to start, and everything I find is about REST API, and I would like to do it vía the Java SDK I've downloaded. I only find a javadoc with all the classes and everything but I don't know what to do with all that info.

I'll appreciate so much a minimum example listing my Virtual Hosts or opening a new Virtual Host or something like that.

**EDIT:** And just found this http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/getting-started-with-the-azure-java-management-libraries/

Tons of hours searching and 1 minute after I post a question I found it, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/getting-started-with-the-azure-java-management-libraries/

Just search `import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management` in Google.